# Magento 2: How to get Firstname and Lastname of abandon guest cart(quote)

Tags: magento2

I need to get Customer Firstname and Lastname from Abandon Guest checkout Cart.
I am not getting a proper solution with my searching on Google.

Anyone have any idea about this.

[image]
Thanks!

Comment: You will get this data only after customer fill the Billing or Shipping Address. And you need to take name from that addresses.

Comment: Yes after filling the billing or shipping address

Answer (score 0):

try this code.

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $session,
) {
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->session = $session;
}

public function execute()
{
    $customerFirstname = $this->session->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getData("firstname");
    $customerLastname = $this->session->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getData("lastname"); 
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this will work?

Comment: This is not working

Comment: Code updated, check that one, but sure customer enter the shipping address.

Comment: Yes i have filled the customer shipping details. But the firstname is showing in quote_address table but not showing in my log file.

Comment: I need to show in cron.php file. This is only working in simple phtml file with object manager otherwise it's showing NULL

Comment: Can you pls provide other solution.. Am really stuck with this.

Comment: I am telling that customer need to fill the set the shippinh and billing address into the quote, means after that steps you will able to get that informmation. are you checking in that same way.

Comment: yes i have added the products in cart and got to checkout page and filled the address details with name so on..

Comment: Check screenshot in my question

Comment: I have checked session is not working in Cron file

Comment: why you need to to use the cron file, you can use the code in your block file or controller file to saving that data.